# How can i create a toggle button with left and right text in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, css-position

**I want to create screen like this, the text is in left and right and toggle button is in center.**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this, all elements are centered

```
  <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center">
     <div style="align-self: center">Binnen</div>
        <ion-toggle></ion-toggle>
     <div style="align-self: center">Buiten</div>
  </div>
```